# C# : Executing neo4j Cypher query that contain path in its Where Clause

Tags: c#-4.0, neo4j

I am trying to fetch FOAF nodes for a given node from the c# codeBehind . The cypher is

```
MATCH (current { PRSN_F_Name: 'MyName' })-[:KNOWS*1..2]->(fof) 
WHERE NOT (current)- [:KNOWS]->(fof) 
RETURN fof.PRSN_F_Name
```

How to implement this query using C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK

I found the answer myself ... it must be like the following :

```
var q = client.Cypher
            .Match("(current { PRSN_F_Name: '" + txtName.Text + "' })-[:KNOWS*1..2]->(fof)")
            .Where("NOT (current)-[:KNOWS]->(fof)")
            .Return((fof) => fof.As<Person>());

        foreach (var result in q.Results)
        {
            ltrFeedback.Text = ltrFeedback.Text + result.PRSN_F_Name + "<br>";
        }
```